# Spring batch-query two databases with one's result as parameter for other

Tags: spring-batch, multiple-databases

Spring batch: I want to query two databases, with the result of query from 1st database as parameter in `IN` clause of second database query. I tried with `CustomItemReader`, but failed. Any one can help!!!

Comment: use a single query with an inner query as values list for IN clause

Comment: Highlighted the keywords